# is it possible to have controls in tablix - ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I wanted to have a drop down box for user to select for each row and based on that the row will be visible or not visible. When an option is selected in dropdown a textbox should appear which allow user to type free text. is this possible in ssrs? if not what are the other ways to handle this scenario.

Comment: You should tell us what you've tried so far, and what the practical problem is (see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq))? The question as is seems a bit hard to understand, e.g. what do you mean by "for user to select for each row" and "allow user to type free text"? Note that you can edit your question.

Comment: what i mean is to have a tablix and at the end of each row i should have a dropdownbox for user to select a reason and based on that reason i will make the row invisible. Is it possible to have dropdown inside a tablix control?

Comment: It's a bit clearer now, I've posted an answer too. Note though that when you have extra info on your question you can *edit your own question* and add the info. You don't have to put it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a bit unclear from the question what you're after. You can't quite use interactive controls like dropdowns and textboxes inside a report (at least, not with the standard controls). There's two things that may be close enough to help you though:

- [Expand/Collapse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220405.aspx) on rows in a tablix.
- [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155917%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) are more interactive, but show up at the top of the report, and not inside the tablix